# during the initial page load need to change the add/edit color

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, kendo-ui

- I am learning angular2.
- during the initial page loads, I need to change the add/edit preference colour.
- can you tell me how to fix it?
- I googled for the load event.
- but I am not able to find out anything.
- providing my code below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zddcxy?file=app/app.component.html

```
<!-- language-all: lang-or-tag-here -->

 public loadColor() {
      console.log('this.changeColor--->');
  }
    <span id="open1" (click)="loadColor()">add/edit prefrence</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ngOnInit and ViewChild decorator

`@ViewChild('open1') el:ElementRef;`

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
  const span = this.el.nativeElement;
  span.style.color = 'red';
}
```

And in HTML add #open1 as ref

```
<span #open1 id="open1" (click)="loadColor()">add/edit prefrence</span>
```

see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvmusm?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: hey thanks for reply....can you explain so that in future I will do it myself....not sure why we are using viewchild and native element

Comment: It's just a way to direct access to the DOM. ViewChild it's a decorator that will allow you to manipulate the reference element in a class. You point to an element of the dom with `#toto` identifier. And you get it with `@ViewChild('toto') el:ElementRef`, then on `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit` you can manipulate this DOM element when  component loads

Answer (score 0):

For catch initial page loads event, you need to use Angular component lifecycle hook. So you need it add `ngOnInit` is called by Angular completed creating the component.

For add `ngOnInit` you need import `OnInit`

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
```

You need to add `ngOnInit` hook method

```
 //implement OnInit's `ngOnInit` method
ngOnInit(){
   console.log('this.changeColor--->');
}
```

For more information https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

I have updated your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzqebz?file=app/app.component.ts